# Class "name" has no member class "name of the member"

Tags: c++, oop, struct, constructor

I`m new to OOP.
Here is the code:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

namespace name
{
    class Class 
    {
    private:
        struct u
        {
            std::string l{};
            struct u* next{};
        };

    public:
        Class(std::string s)
            :
            u::l(s)
        { }
            
        ~Class() = default;
    };
};
```

When I compile this I`m getting an errors like this:

```
Error (active)  E1018   class "name::Class::u" has no member class "l"
```

```
Error   C2614   'name::Class': illegal member initialization: 'l' is not a base or member name
```

Can you help me. I will glad you.

Comment: Your class indeed does not have a member named `u` - because that is the name of a type that you defined. You didn't create an actual member of that type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this

```
    struct u
    {
        std::string l{};
        struct u* next{};
    };
```

does not do what you seem to think it does, it is just defining the type 'u', it does not say that 'Class' contains an instance of 'u'.

Plus you have to have a constructor in order to use that initialization syntax

```
namespace name
{
    class Class
    {
    private:
        struct u
        {
            std::string l{};
            struct u* next{};
            u(string s) :l(s) {} <<<=== here is Class::u constructor
        };

        u _u; <<<==== I want Class to contain a Class::u

    public:
        Class(std::string s)
            :
            _u(s) <<< ====use constructor
        {
        }

        ~Class() = default;
    };
};
```

Comment: @progersteel just a tip: you should use less generic names in SO posts. It will help to resolve issues faster.

Comment: Less generic names help everywhere. Good code self-documents with descriptive identifiers that allow a reasonably attentive reader to infer the purpose and usage of variables, types, and functions. If the reader is familiar with the fundamentals of C++ they should be able to make reasonable and correct assumptions about the goals and intended behaviour of the code.